# Android Edittext in BaseAdapter not working?

Tags: android, android-edittext, baseadapter

I have a listview with BaseAdapter and size is 10. In each adapter index layout there is an EditText. But i am having issue with keyboard input. The edittext InputType is Integer but the keyboard is opening with Text Keyboard and also no input text is getting added to the edittext.

**MyCode :**

```
public class NameAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;

private ViewHolder holder = null;

public NameAdapter(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return "Test";
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 10;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public EditText nameInput;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, parent, false);
        holder.nameInput = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_etd);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.nameInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

    return convertView;
}
 }
```

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#ffffff"
          android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_etd"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Enter Number"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am not able to find the reason for this weird issue. Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: You have set the inputType in the XML, but why set the inputType of EditText again in your code? Or you can try this code: `edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);`

Comment: I have added the InputType in the getView but the issue is still same

Comment: U can use android:digits="0123456789" in your xml.

Comment: No issue , i have solved it by giving android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to the activity in the Manifest...